# Should be + First form of verb

Tags: grammar

I am writing some document where I write sentence(active voice) like that :
Dialog should be launch.
File should be download.

Is this sentence are correct or may I use past participle with should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct sentences are:

- **A/the dialogue should be launched**. (It's not clear which article we should use in this case. Use *a* if you mean "one", "some kind of", "another" or use *the* if you refer to something mentioned before, some definite dialogue)
- **The file should be downloaded**. (As far as I understand, you mean some definite file here)

In the sentences above we need to use *should be + past participle* because it is the grammar of the passive voice.